# Элементарная web страница на ubuntu сервере

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, gui

Есть Ubuntu Server, машинка достаточно слабенькая графически, но для консольного сервера прекрасная. Существует монитор, к которому подключен сервер. Необходимо, чтобы на экране отображалась Web страница (некого рода монитор).

Пробовал ставить Ubuntu Desktop - не потянула, слишком стало грустно, лагала просто невыносимо.

Как реализовать поставленную задачу?

Comment: Поставить иксы и браузер, очевидно

Comment: @andreymal , спасибо большое! Не знал сначала о такой вещи даже... Всё почитал, промучился, поставил, настроил) Запустил апач и связал сокетами ;)